# Is it really true that the Cartesian product $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^3$ is not equal to $\mathbb R^5$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably going to turn out to be an embarrassment for me (took me an hour to get the courage to post this), but I can't figure this out.

Using the [definition of cartesian product from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), we have
$$\mathbb R^3=\big\{(x_1,x_2,x_3); x_1,x_2,x_3\in \mathbb R \big\}$$
$$\mathbb R^2=\big\{(x_1,x_2); x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R \big\}$$
$$\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^3 = \big\{\big((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4,x_5)\big); (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2, (x_3,x_4,x_5) \in R^3 \big\} $$

Which does not seem to be equal to $\mathbb R^5$, which has $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ as elements instead of ordered pairs of 2-tuples and 3-tuples.

Please make the universe functional again, thanks!

Comment: This has *definitely* been discussed at least twice before.

Comment: Which is another reason why this will be an embarrassement. The problem is, how do you search for things like this? I tried a couple of searches but couldn't find anything. Perhaps improving my searching skills rather than set theoretic knowledge is what I am after :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338319/associativity-of-cartesian-product should include an answer.

Comment: @DahnJahn: Part of what helps the effectiveness of searches in general is using titles that are not comprised solely of MathJax.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313958/some-questions-about-the-cartesian-product (and I'm sure others too, but too lazy to find them after finding at least two occasions! :-))

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, I didn't think of seeing it as an problem with the associative property! Thanks

Comment: @ZevChonoles True, I will think about that from now on. Any suggestions for a better title?

Comment: There is a natural *bijection* \begin{align*}\mathbf R^2\times\mathbf R^3&\longrightarrow\mathbf R^5\\ \bigl((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4,x_5)\bigr)&\longmapsto(x_1,x_2,x_3, x_4,x_5) \end{align*} which is an isomorphism.