# Prove that $X \times Y \times Z = X \times (Y \times Z) = (X \times Y) \times Z$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$X$ and $Y$ are sets. 
$X \times Y$ denotes the cartesian product of the set X and Y. 
It's given that none of the sets is empty.

Comment: What does $=$ mean?  And what are your thoughts?

Comment: @JasonDeVito , I believe that means equivalent relations. I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not true.

Comment: There is a canonical bijection between each of these three expressions and they are often used interchangeably, however they are not technically the same.  Consider the simple case of $X,Y,Z$ all being the one element sets $\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}$ respectively.  $X\times Y\times Z$ would result in $\{(x,y,z)\}$.  $X\times (Y\times Z)$ would result in $\{(x,(y,z))\}$ and $(X\times Y)\times Z$ would result in $\{((x,y),z)\}$

Comment: See this discussion about the so-called [associativity of cartesian product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338319)

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a bijection between $(X \times Y) \times Z$ and $X \times (Y \times Z)$.

the bijection $f : (X \times Y) \times Z \to X \times (Y \times Z)$ can be defined as $f((x,y),z) = (x,(y,z))$

Now you can prove that this is a bijection by showing it has a two sided inverse.

Comment: That we can construct such a bijection does not directly answer the question of "*are these sets equal?*"